# In DF2014, what causes Traps to attack own dwarves?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

[The wiki (currently) says:](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Trap)

> Stone-fall, weapon and cage traps will be triggered by most hostile
>   entities entering their tile, with the possible exception of thieves,
>   flying creatures and other occasional nasty fun surprises. Any
>   unconscious creature will trigger traps, including your own dwarves.

However this does not seem to be true.

I had started a new fort,
Usually I would use wooden Cage traps, until I had my hands on some weapons, 
then I would mix them with Weapon traps.
In this embark I had no trees.
so I thought I would start my trapping off with some stone traps.
Just in case.

So I got the basic traps near my entrance,
then I started to install a few more in crucial zones -- heavily trafficked corridors.
I noticed occationally a message would say "Urist McDwarf has been found dead".
At first I thought this was a case of me having a vampire (And that the Vampire death message had changed -- to make it less obvious.)

Then I thought I might check on the combat logs -- turns out my dwarves were being killed by boulders.
So I thought: Must be the stone traps -- I guess I will pull them out and replace them with Weapon Traps.

That was !!Fun!! instead of a simple death from a stone to the skull, 
now the dwarves were periodically being sprayed across my corridor by the Spinning Discs.
The deaths were no doubt quicker, but more brutal -- and Horrified anyone who witnessed them.
In true DF fashion this sparked a tantrum spiral that claimed the fortress.

I never had a dwarf caught in my cage traps, but there were only 6, (half of which were in the almost untrafficed caverns.)

---

So something has changed in the way traps decide who to kill.
I don't think my dwarves were passing out periodically on top of my traps.

What is the new condition for traps to attack/activate on your own dwarves?

Comment: It's not the traps deciding who to kill, it's the dwarves deciding to enter that square. I would guess it's because the corridor is so busy.

Comment: @starsplusplus conscious dwarves never triggered traps before, and dwarves never tried to path around them.

Comment: What happens if you put the trap in a corridor one tile wide? Is the corridor blocked or do they go through the trap?

Comment: It definitely doesn't block the corridor, I had them blocking my corridor that was 3 wide. 
and there was plenty of traffic though it, before and after the traps.
When I get that a new fortress up to having mechanisms, I will check that against corridors that are 1 wide, but I don't see that it would make a difference.

Comment: Is it possible they're falling onto the traps from above due to climbing weirdness?

Comment: Have you tried reproducing this in another fort?

Comment: @RavenDreamer: No i have been having ... !!Fun!! forts, that have had no stone...

Comment: I had lots of caged dwarfs in my busy 1-tile trapped corridor a couple of months ago. I fixed it by making them walk around, after getting fed up of deploying the cages just to let them out. They seemed to be quite happy to be in there though!

Answer (score 1):

**Drowsy** dwarves were triggering traps even in 0.34.11.
And they are still triggering them in 0.40.x

The evidence is that the only thing I've seen them cancel due to being caged is Sleep.

Comment: What? No they do not. Drowsy dwarves do not get caught in traps. Easy way to test. Set up a bedroom, and put a trap in front of the bed. They do not get attacked/caught in the trap.

Comment: My comment was about 0.34.11 have not done 0.40

Comment: Drowsy, usually no. Stunned and staggering, generally yes.